# python pandas how to edit value of duplicate?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to change value of my duplicate. Here is my dataframe:

```
  sku
FAT-001
FAT-001
FAT-001
FAT-002
FAT-002
```

my expected data frame will be look like this

```
  sku
FAT-001 #don't want to change first value of duplicate 
FAT-001-01
FAT-001-02
FAT-002
FAT-002-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df["number"] = df.groupby("sku").cumcount()
df.apply(lambda x: x.sku + ("" if x.number == 0 else "-" + str(x.number).rjust(2,"0")), axis = 1)
```

or:

```
df["number"] = "-" + df.groupby("sku").cumcount().astype(str).str.rjust(2, '0')
df.number[df["number"].eq("-" + "0" * 2)] = ""
df.sku + df.number
```

my output:

```
0       FAT-001
1    FAT-001-01
2    FAT-001-02
3       FAT-002
4    FAT-002-01
dtype: object
```

explanation:

what is `groupby`? it is a `sql-inspired` command that give you some element base on every unique element... for example: length, max, list or other...

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,2],
    [1,3],
    [1,4],
    [2,5],
    [2,6],
], columns=["id","number"])
df.groupby("id").agg({"number": len})
```

give you:

```
    number
id  
1   3
2   2
```

the number of every unique elements, or

```
df.groupby("id").agg({"number": list})
```

give you

```
    number
id  
1   [2, 3, 4]
2   [5, 6]
```

and you can try `max` or `min` or `first`...

using `agg`, you can specify what you want for every column... if you have more than one (except what was `groupby`), you can specify something for each `column`...

except `agg`, there are other methods for `goupped` dataframes: like `cumcount`, that set index every `row` for each `group`, I mean it reset `index` for every `group`:

```
df.groupby("sku").cumcount()
```

output:

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    1
```

your first `FAT-001` get `index`: 0, next: 1, ... and for `FAT-002`, first get index 0 again...

so, we have two part that you want, now... therefore we must find a way to join them for every `row`: *`axis:1` in `apply` means for every row*

so, you have one exception: you don't want `index` for every row of each group... so change it to "", empty:

```
df.apply(lambda x: "" if x.number == 0 else str(x.number), axis = 1)
```

:

```
0     
1    1
2    2
3     
4    1
dtype: object
```

your `0` and `3` rows are for new-group...

next, your desired format is: 01,02,... a `0` for every index. pandas has a method that convert every string to string with desired length with an arbitrary `char:` rjust(desird_length, arbitrary_char)

how works: if you call that as `rjust(2,"0")`, it dos not change `"22"` or other 2-char, 3-char, ... strings, but, if your string length be 1 like `1` will be converted to `01` and ... (notice that there are a method called `ljust` too :))

```
df["number"] = df.groupby("sku").cumcount()
df.apply(lambda x: "" if x.number == 0 else str(x.number).rjust(2,"0"), axis = 1)
```

```
0      
1    01
2    02
3      
4    01
dtype: object
```

and `if` statement can written as:

```
if x.number == 0:
   return ""
else:
    return "-" + str(x.number).rjust(2,"0")
```

and some points:

1. what is `astype(str)`: it convert every element to string, and works like `str(x)`, but for every element. why? to add "-" before it and using `rjust`.
2. what is `eq`? it is `is-equal?` and return `True` for each row if be equal to value, and `False` otherwise.
3. why `df.number[df["number"].eq("-" + "0" * 2)] = ""`? because we convert all first elements of each group to `""`
4. why `"-" + "0" * 2`? because we add `"-"` and ljust in previous line so we must use correct value: `"-00"`. and why `"0" * 2`? because you can use every number for `ljust length` like 10 and set it there, too

Comment: getting 0 for first duplicate FAT-001 but I want empty row for first duplicate and also getting 1,2,3 which will be FAT-001-01, FAT-001-02,FAT-001-03

Comment: @ByHala try **or** part

Comment: it's working.  can you please explain this line of code `df.apply(lambda x: x.sku + ("" if x.number == 0 else "-" + str(x.number).rjust(2,"0")), axis = 1)` How it's working.?specifically  what doing ` df.groupby("sku").cumcount().astype` What is groupby, cumcount and astype?

Comment: the second code is better than the first, imo. Just a suggestion: `df.number[df["number"].eq("-" + "0" * 2)]` could be written as `df.loc[df["number"].eq("-00"), "number"]`. +1

Comment: @ByHala, I edit my post, it is in simple word for you and future reader... because may seems very simple, I'm sorry for that :))

Comment: @MoRe  great man. It help me lot and also will help others people.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @MoRe's answer, use `groupby.cumcount` to create groups; then you could use `str.zfill` to pad 0s and `mask` the first elements of each group:

```py
groups = df.groupby('sku').cumcount()
df['new'] = df['sku'] + ('-' + groups.astype('string').str.zfill(2)).mask(groups.eq(0), '')
```

Output:

```py
       sku         new
0  FAT-001     FAT-001
1  FAT-001  FAT-001-01
2  FAT-001  FAT-001-02
3  FAT-002     FAT-002
4  FAT-002  FAT-002-01
```

Comment: Thanks for your answare. I want to  know is it possible to set unique value for null row. Assume I have  index 5, 6 and 7 where I don't have any sku. is it possible to set unique value in row of "new "column for index 5, 6 and 7 like  sku001 for index 5 , sku002 for index 6, sku003 for index 7

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative one-liner:

```
 df.sku = df.sku + df.groupby('sku').cumcount().apply(lambda x: f"-{x:02d}" if x > 0 else '')
```

Output:

```
          sku
0     FAT-001
1  FAT-001-01
2  FAT-001-02
3     FAT-002
4  FAT-002-01
```