# python pandas how to set unique value for null row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have an data frame like this:

```
       sku         new-sku
0  FAT-001     FAT-001
1  FAT-001  FAT-001-01
2  FAT-001  FAT-001-02
3  FAT-002     FAT-002
4  FAT-002  FAT-002-01
5           
6            
7 FAT-003   FAT-003
8            
9
```

here is my code:

```
groups = df.groupby('sku').cumcount()
df['new'] = df['sku'] + ('-' + groups.astype('string').str.zfill(2)).mask(groups.eq(0), '')
```

My expected result will be look like this:

```
       sku         new-sku
0  FAT-001     FAT-001
1  FAT-001  FAT-001-01
2  FAT-001  FAT-001-02
3  FAT-002     FAT-002
4  FAT-002  FAT-002-01
5           FAT-null-01
6           FAT-null-02
7 FAT-003   FAT-003
8           FAT-null-03
9           FAT-null-04
```

**It will increment by +1 for every new null row.**

The constructor:

```py
{'sku': {0: 'FAT-001', 1: ' ', 2: ' ', 3: 'FAT-002', 4: 'FAT-002', 5: ' ', 6: ' ', 7: 'FAT-003', 8: 'FAT-003', 9: 'FAT-004'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72094000/17521785), We could add a `mask` when we create groups using `groupby.cumcount` for the white space rows and adjust accordingly:

```py
groups = df.groupby('sku').cumcount()
groups = groups.mask(df['sku'].eq(' '), groups+1)
df['new-sku'] = df['sku'].replace(' ', 'FAT-null') + ('-' + groups.astype('string').str.zfill(2)).mask(groups.eq(0), '')
```

Output:

```py
   ID      sku      new-sku
0   1  FAT-001      FAT-001
1   2           FAT-null-01
2   3           FAT-null-02
3   4  FAT-002      FAT-002
4   5  FAT-002   FAT-002-01
5   6           FAT-null-03
6   7           FAT-null-04
7   8  FAT-003      FAT-003
8   9  FAT-003   FAT-003-01
9  10  FAT-004      FAT-004
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244440/discussion-between-enke-and-byhala).